# HELP! navigation stack setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys!!!!!

I am now setting up the navigation stack for my robot.  I have all the requirement, except that I use the diffdrive_plugin and the gazebo_ros_camera plugin to fulfill the requirement. But these plugin are not strictly package. What should I do?

Using

rostopic list:

```
/camera_info
/clock
/cmd_vel
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/image_raw
/image_raw/compressed
/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_raw/compressedDepth
/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_raw/theora
/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/set_hfov
/set_joint_trajectory
/set_update_rate
/tf
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64584/help!-navigation-stack-setup/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a good set of tutorials that explain everything: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-09**:
Hi, I have follow your link, could you please help me out on a quick question?
http://answers.ros.org/question/64615/map-and-navigation-stack/